# How do I output a multi-line string in YAML?

Tags: yaml, localization, newline, line-breaks

I want to create a multi-line string key in YAML, for example:

```
landing:
  description: |
    We invite you to take 20 minutes to complete this form.
    What is it for? Your answers will allow us to get to know you.
    Note: There are no right or wrong answers.
```

This seems to be displayed well in my Visual Studio Code editor. I use `|`, and then I indent each line using the `Tab` key when I want go in a new line.

This YAML file (and many others that I created) are synced with Crowdin, a cloud-based localization management platform. When I view the key in Crowdin, I can see the multi-lines are preserved exactly as I'd expect.

I am not 100% sure of what happens after that as I am a bit new to this, but I know that our developers use JSON files and call upon the various string keys needed.
However, in the actual output in the product, the new lines are not preserved, and everything is displayed in one single line.

Is there a way to ensure that the new lines are preserved in the output, in the same way as they are written in the YAML file?

Alternatively, is it possible to use `<br />` or `\n`?

Thank you very much in advance for your insight.

Comment: Welcome to SO! YAML is a data serialization language and doesn't output anything per se. Please edit your question to include information on what you're doing with your YAML, so that we see how you generate output from it.

Comment: Hello @flyx - thank you so much for your comment! I have added a bit more information that I thought could be a bit more helpful, but I'm not sure if it's sufficient. I have to say I'm a little new to all this, so I'm not 100% sure of the overall procedure and setup/what happens on the dev's side. Please let me know if there's anything else in particular that is needed to understand the issue and I will liaise with the right team! Thank you :)

Comment: YAML does not define how text is rendered, it only defines how to enter text. It is *your product* that does the rendering. We cannot possibly know how it does that. You'll need to show your product's code if you want us to tell you how you can get your text to render newlines.